# content_length of parquet file on redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to upload files from S3 to redshift and created a manifest json file to do so:

```
{  
   "entries":[  
      {  
         "url":"s3://xyz/xyz/asda1.parquet",
         "mandatory":true,
         "meta":{  
            "content_length":99
         }
      },
      {  
         "url":"s3://xyz/xyz/asda2.parquet",
         "mandatory":true,
         "meta":{  
            "content_length":99
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is form an example I found in the AWS documentation for parquet files : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#copy-command-examples-manifest

When I run the copy command though, I get an error which says "has an invalid version number". From researching on stackoverflow, it seems like the content_length has to be set properly. I am not sure how I can get the content_length of my files. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The meta key contains a content_length key with a value that is the `actual size of the file in bytes`. So I think you have to use the s3 cli to get the file size and generate the manifest file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the **content_length** by executing **aws s3 ls** command

```
aws s3 ls s3://xyz/xyz/asda.parquet
2020-11-25 09:33:44        2003 asda.parquet
```

2003 -> this value is the content_length value that needs to be specified in your manifest file